# During the development of widevine in cobalt

Tags: cobalt, widevine

- current state

During the development of widevine in cobalt, I put the libwidevine_cdm_shared.so file into cobalt and the following problem occurred.

```
    libprotobuf FATAL ../../third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:89] This program was compiled against versionterminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
    what():  This program was compiled against version 2.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.0.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/home1/green/lekail/Widevine/SDK_Source/out/amlogic/Debug/obj/gen/protoc_out/device_files.pb.cc".)
```

What is the problem?

(cobalt version - RC9  ,Widevine CE CDM version- 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

The error message has all the details.
Please compile libwidevine_cdm_shared.so against protobuf 3.0.0. If you didn't compile it by yourself, ask the author of libwidevine_cdm_shared.so to compile it against protobuf 3.0.0.